# gnuplot - make plot go to edge of graph

Tags: gnuplot

I want my graph lines to go from one edge of the graph area to the other, but for some reason there is a blank area between the edge and the lines. It doesn't seem like I am talking about the margins as setting them to 0 gets rid of the whitespace *outside* of the graph, which I am okay with.

How do I get this graph:
[image]
to look like this?
[image]
Here is my code:

```
#!/usr/bin/gnuplot
reset
set terminal png size 800,400

set xdata time
set timefmt "%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S"
set format x "%H:%M"
set xlabel "time"

set ylabel "load percentage"
set yrange [0:100]

set title "Performance last 24 hours"
unset colorbox
set key reverse Left outside
set grid

set style data linespoints
set style line 1 lt 2 pt '' lc rgb "red" lw 3
set style line 2 lt 2 pt '' lc rgb "blue" lw 2


plot "/path/to/data.dat" using 1:3 ls 1 title "CPU %", \
""  using 1:4 ls 2 title "MEM %"
```

Comment: If you want to adjust the range of the x axis, and in particular avoid the automatic extension to the next tic mark, you can do that with `set xrange` (see, in particular, `help noextend`).

Comment: Use `set autoscale xfix`, https://stackoverflow.com/q/26400968/2604213

Comment: @user8153 I just looked into that, but couldn't figure out how to set the range for `08:00:00` to `08:00:00`.

Comment: @Christoph Thanks, that did the trick! If you answer with that I'll mark it as accepted. Or would it me more appropriate to remove this question or mark it as a duplicate?